# $(window).resize() or $(window).on('resize') not firing when the window is maximized or restored. Is there another trigger for these events?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Interestingly, I cannot reproduce the problem in Codepen or a simple basic page like in the example below. Also, the code works fine when resizing by dragging. It's as if maximize and restore are not considered "resizing".

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  div {
   width: 10px;
   height: 10px;
   border: 3px solid red;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div></div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script> 
  <script>
  $(window).resize(function() {
   $("div").outerWidth($("body").outerWidth());
  });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem only occurs in a WordPress project I'm working on. Is there a specific circumstance that could be causing this issue? Or is there a different event to look for, other than 'resize'?

Comment: Does it still not work if you try changing all the `$` to `jQuery`?  Afaik, wordpress usually runs jQuery in no conflict mode so `$ != jQuery` Ref. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: Check the Wordpress CSS rules and JS code that might interact with the `div` you are trying to modify. Your code is fine if not it woudn't work in your example.

Comment: Check jQuery in Wordpress is working as expected as @Taplar said. You can also open developer tools in the browser and try to use your jQuery code from the console.

Comment: Are you sure it is an issue with onresize or the fact that the content inside is resized to the max and than it does not change the value?

Comment: @Taplar all my scripts are wrapped in jQuery so I can use the dollar sign. Remember, the code actually works if the window is resized by dragging. It only doesn't work on maximize and restore. Same behavior in all browsers.

Answer (score 4):

It appears this is a non-issue because the resize event is firing just fine, as demonstrated by a `console.log('Resized!');` inside the handler.

Something like a race condition is what was actually happening: my `outerWidth()`'s weren't always returning the new, recalculated values. (Sometimes they would, further adding to the confusion.)

I wonder if there's a cleaner solution to this than adding a delay...

Answer (score 0):

Just got the problem today when trying to got the browser height after resize event.

It's appear when maximized, the value of witdh / height are not immediatly correct.

Adding a delay before any processing do the the trick for me.

```
 methods: {
      sleep(ms) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
      },
      async setTableHeight() {
        await this.sleep(250) // Wait some delay for size to be correct
        // do something
        var totalHeight = document.getElementById('q-app').offsetHeight
        document.getElementById("table").style.height = (totalHeight  - 60) + "px";
        console.log('size = ' + totalHeight )
      }

}
```